# Unwanted characters when appending a newline in python3

Tags: python

I am appending newline to file if it doesn't exist but it appending unwanted characters.

Input file:

```
abc
```

Code to append newline if it does exist:

```py
with open(file_location, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        if not data.endswith('\n'):
            with open(file_location, 'a') as newline_file:
                writer = csv.writer(newline_file)
                writer.writerow('\n')
```

or alternatively:

```py
with open(local_file_location, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        if not data.endswith('\n'):
            with open(local_file_location, 'a') as newline_file:
                writer = csv.writer(newline_file)
                writer.writerow("\n")
```

Giving the output below:

```
abc"
"
```

I do not want these:

```
""
```

I want the output below:

```
abc
```

How can I achieve this also let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you use a `csv.writer` if you don't want to write a file in CSV format?

Comment: @mkrieger1: I'm assuming they have an existing CSV file that happened to be made with a tool that didn't append a newline on the final line, and some other tool gets fussy when it lacks the final line (or they just don't like when they `cat` it to the screen and the prompt appears on the same line as the final line of the CSV). If it's already CSV, you want to keep observing CSV conventions when adding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a newline as if it were a row of data, so it got quoted to keep it treated as part of the data, not the end of a row (it's treating the `str` as an iterable of its characters, where each character is a separate field, exactly as if you called `writer.writerow(["\n"])`). If you want to make it write the end of a row without writing any fields, pass an empty iterable, e.g.:

```
writer.writerow([])
```

Skipping the `csv` module is a naive solution you should avoid, as CSV is quite sensitive to how newlines are handled, so you do still want to use `writerow` here, rather than directly `write`ing to the underlying file.

On the subject of "CSV is quite sensitive to how newlines are handled" your code right now is wrong; the `csv` module is quite clear that you need to pass `newline=''` to the `open` calls so the `csv.writer` has complete control over how newlines are handled (for example, a newline in a field that's part of the data might be written as `'\n'`, while a newline separating records is `'\r\n'` in common dialects).

So your code should be:

```
with open(file_location) as file:  # No newline='' needed since we want the translation
    data = file.read()[-1:]  # Don't store complete file data indefinitely; only care about last character
# May as well remove from with above, we don't need the file to remain open
if not data.endswith('\n'):
    # Use newline='' so csv module controls how end of record is written
    with open(file_location, 'a', newline='') as newline_file:
        writer = csv.writer(newline_file)
        writer.writerow([])  # [] can be replaced with () or '' or any empty iterable if you prefer; [] is easier to see, () is probably fastest by a hair
```

Comment: This works, but please note that you still have to remove the quotation marks manually from the file.

Comment: @Nineteendo: I assume you mean the quotation marks the OP already wrote there with their incorrect solution? This won't add any quotation marks itself.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This solution won't get rid off them.